# How to populate environment variable section in allure report while serving a junit report generated by Ginkgo framework?

Tags: junit, allure, ginkgo

I'm using Ginkgo to run some tests written in Golang.

```
 ginkgo -r --keep-going --junit-report=report_all.xml -v
```

After the run completes I get a nice visualization using `allure serve`

[image: allure report]

Before running my tests I set some environment variables which are not visible here.
Is there any way I can show some information about setup, app version in this section?